Redirecting from subfolder to new subdomain
I am trying to write a  redirect /  for the following
Current setup:

subfolder: forum
URL: website/forum/

New Set up

Root
URL: forum.newwebsite/

What I need to do is redirect:
https://website/forum/demoforum to https://forum.newwebsite/demoforum
Everything from the last needs to be replicated on the direct / rewrite.
I have tried the following but they dont work:
location /forum/ {
    return 301 https://forum.newwebsite.org;
}

location /forum/ {
    return 301 https://forum.newwebsite.org$request_uri;
} 


please try this:
location /forum/ {
    rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ https://forum.newwebsite.org/$1 permanent;
}

